# How to upload the html file inside jenkins?

Tags: file, jenkins, upload, server

I am new to the server side work. I have requirement that I should upload the .html file to the jenkin. I don't know which server they are using. Can anyone guide me to find the server that is used for the jenkin and process to upload a file?

Comment: You want to upload a html to jenkins? Why? What is the use case?

Comment: I have to store the html page there so that I can use email option in the "Jenkins" application.

Comment: Please explain more in detail. Are you talking about mail html templates?

Answer (score 0):

If you can push the file to a remote repository like Github or Bitbucket then you can have Jenkins check out that repository and file will be in `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/your-job-name/workspace/your-html-file.html`. This is the first solution that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you're talking about **Archiving Artifacts**.

In your jobs (that generates the html files) go to configure -> Go to the post build section -> add a post build operation -> Archive the artifacts.

Indicate the **/*.html files or just the name of the file you want to upload to the master and save.

Then you can use [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to move this file from the master to any workspace\slave you want.

Good luck!